# Sliding Div's removing 1st one from left and adding new from right

Tags: jquery, html, sliding

I have three div section horizontaly what i want is that after some time interval the left most div is removed and a new div is added from the right most direction

this is the html file having 3 div sections within an outer div

**HTML**

```
<div id="sub-category">
  <div id="sub-category1">
  </div>
  <div id="sub-category2">
  </div>
  <div id="sub-category3">
  </div>
</div>
```

in the jquery a time interval of 5sec after every 5sec SlideDivSection(). Right now it removing the first div and shifting but it is not adding the new div to the right.

**Jquery**

```
 function SlideDiv(){
        setInterval(function(){SlideDivSection()}, 5000);
 }

 function SlideDivSection(){            
     $("#sub-category1").slideUp();    
     $("#sub-category1").remove();    
     $("#sub-category2").attr('id',"sub-category1");//setting the id of sub-cateogry2 to sub category1

     $("#sub-category2").attr("id","sub-category2");//setting the id of sub-cateogry3 to sub category2


// now adding a new div    
     $("#sub-cateogry").append("<div id='#sub-cateogry3'></div>");
//giving slidedown effect to newly created div
     $("#sub-cateogry3").slideUp();
   }

    $("document").ready(SlideDiv);
```

**CSS**

```
#sub-category {
    border:solid 0px black;
    width:686px;
    height:275px;
    position: relative;
    margin:5px;
}
#sub-category1 {
    border:solid 1px black;
    width:223px;
    height:293px;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    background-color:grey;
}
#sub-category2 {
    border:solid 1px black;
    width:223px;
    height:293px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    float:left;
    background-color:lightskyblue;
}
#sub-category3 {
    border:solid 1px black;
    width:222px;
    height:293px;
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: Replace `$("document").ready(SlideDiv);` with `$("document").ready(function() { SlideDiv(); } );`. It's better practice :)

Comment: I have updated my answer which provides a solution to your js code.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to do something like this  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pZBMh/)

### markup

```
<div id="sub-category">
    <div id="sub-category1" class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div id="sub-category2" class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div id="sub-category3" class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

### css

```
    #sub-category{
        border: 0 solid black;
        height: 295px;
        margin: 5px 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        width: 675px;
     }
     .item{
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        top: 0;
        width: 223px;
        height: 293px;
        border: solid 1px black;
        background: #046380;
        font: 44px/262px georgia;
        text-align: center;
        font-style: italic
     }
     #sub-category1{
        background-color: grey;
     }
     #sub-category2{
        background-color: #ffc; left: 225px;
     }
     #sub-category3{
        left: 450px;
        background-color: lightgreen;
     }
```

### and the javascript

```
    function SlideDivSection() {
        var items = ['sub-category1', 'sub-category2', 'sub-category3'];
        var container = $('#sub-category')
        var item_width = 225;

        window.setInterval(function () {

           var first = $('.item:first', container);
           var faux_id = first.attr('id') + 'faux';
           var faux_elem = $($('<div/>').append(first.clone()).html()).attr('id', faux_id).css({
              left: item_width * items.length,
              backgroundColor: first.css('background-color')
           })
           container.append(faux_elem);
           faux_elem = $('#' + faux_id, container);

           $('.item', container).animate({
              left: '-=' + item_width
           }, 500, function () {
              first.remove();
              faux_elem.attr('id', faux_elem.attr('id').replace('faux', ''))
           })
        }, 2000)
     }

     $(function(){
        SlideDivSection();
     })
```

This solution removes an item from one end and inserts it again from the other end. So you end up **seamlessly** cycling your initial elements. This behavior could be changed to "adding a new (and distinct) element" after removing an element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Allendar/Qudvw/)

**HTML**

```
/* Same as your original */
```

**CSS**

```
/* Same as your original */
```

**JavaScript**

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#sub-category3').remove();

        $('#sub-category1').attr('id', 'sub-category2');
        $('#sub-category2').attr('id', 'sub-category3');

        $('#sub-category').prepend('<div id="sub-category1"></div>');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Take heed; you won't see a visual change unless you put content in the DIV's, as the style is passed on also ;) So it's not "not working" because you see nothing :P

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed your javascript, there were a few small errors, but seems to be working fine now.

updated jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    setInterval(function(){SlideDivSection()}, 5000);

 function SlideDivSection(){            

    //fade out and remove div1
    $("#sub-category1").fadeOut(1000, function(){$(this).remove();});   

    $("#sub-category2").attr('id',"sub-category1").html('1');//setting the id of sub-cateogry2 to sub category1    
    $("#sub-category3").attr("id","sub-category2").html('2');//setting the id of sub-cateogry3 to sub category2

    //create new div
    var newDiv = '<div id="sub-category3" style="display:none;">asdas</div>';

    //add new div and fade in    
    $("#sub-category").append(newDiv);
    $("#sub-category3").fadeIn(400);
}

});
```

By using chaining you can use one line of code to remove your divs and hide them. By using the callback of slideUp will ensure that your div is only removed after the slide up animation has finished..

```
$("#sub-category1").slideUp(1000, function(){$(this).remove();});
```

Here is a working JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/EmxnF/4

Comment: The OP states it wants to remove the `<div>` explicitly. So hiding would be a bit ugly ;)

Answer (score 0):

Typos :

```
/* you wrote : */ $("#sub-category2").attr("id","sub-category2");
/* should be : */ $("#sub-category3").attr("id","sub-category2");

/* you wrote : */ $("#sub-cateogry").append("<div id='#sub-cateogry3'></div>");
/* should be : */ $("#sub-category").append("<div id='sub-category3'></div>");

/* you wrote : */ $("#sub-cateogry3").slideUp();
/* should be : */ $("#sub-category3").slideUp();
```

Correcting this makes your code work (except for the effects) : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ChKW/).

If you want to see your first div slideUp, you have to wait for the animation to end before calling `$('#div-subcategory1').remove()`. You should use a callback on slideUp.

If you want to animate the div you insert, you should insert it hidden, and use `slideToggle`.

```
 $("#sub-category1").slideUp(function(){
     $("#sub-category1").remove();
     $("#sub-category2").attr('id',"sub-category1");
     $("#sub-category3").attr("id","sub-category2");

     $("#sub-category").append("<div id='sub-category3' style='display: none'></div>");
     $("#sub-category3").slideToggle();
 });
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ChKW/2/).

As stated before, if you want to set something more than juste `SlideDiv` on document load, it is better to write :

```
$(document).ready( function(){
     SlideDiv();
     //add more stuff here
});
```